# Replace 50% of characters (randomly) in a String

Tags: python, random, replace

I'm using `replace()` to distort data, and I'd like to have a "high distortion" setting where every instance is replaced, and a "low distortion" setting where there's a 50% chance of each instance being replaced. For example:

```
x = "aaaaaaaaaa"
x = x.replace("a", "b")
'bbbbbbbbbb'

x = "aaaaaaaaaa"
x = x.5050replace("a", "b")
'aabbabbaab'
```

Without re-writing `replace()`, how could someone do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [random](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module:

```
import random
x = ''.join(i if random.randint(0, 1) else 'b' for i in x)
```

This code essentially 'replaces' each letter in `x` if `random.randint` evaluates to `0` with `'b'`, and leaves it as it is otherwise.

If your string is something for complicated like `'aacakedaaasa'` and you only want to replace the `'a'`s, then try this:

```
x = ''.join(i if i != 'a' or random.randint(0, 1) else 'b' for i in x)
```

This doesn't do anything if the letter isn't `'a'`, and if it is, then replaces it with `'b'` if `random.randint` returns `0`, like the previous example.

Comment: You don't need the brackets -- it'll work equally well without it.

Comment: @DSM of course, forgot about that, thanks for the reminder, though!

Comment: This will give an almost 50% replacement but not exact 50% replacement

Comment: It seems to be working, but the data is so long and complicated I can't really check. If I wanted to decrease it to a 1/3 chance, would I replace `random.randint(0, 1)` with `random.randint(0, 2)`?

Comment: @tkbx Yeah, that's what you need to do (but I'm sure you've figured that out already)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [random.choice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to build a new list from a population of your string and a string of `b`s of equal size

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> x = "aaaaaaaaaa"
>>> ''.join(random.sample(x + "b"*len(x), len(x)))
'baabbbbbba'
```

**Note** This is twice as fast compared to comprehending the string using with `random.randint`

```
>>> stmt_ab = "''.join(random.sample(x + 'b'*len(x), len(x)))"
>>> stmt_v = "''.join(i if random.randint(0, 1) else 'b' for i in x)"
>>> import timeit
>>> t1_v = timeit.Timer(stmt_v,setup="from __main__ import x, random")
>>> t1_ab = timeit.Timer(stmt_ab,setup="from __main__ import x, random")
>>> t1_v.timeit(100000)
2.749679788532113
>>> t1_ab.timeit(100000)
1.3974490402988167
```

---

Instead if you want an exact 50% replacement, you can use `random.shuffle`

```
>>> x = "aaaaaaaaaa"
>>> x = list(x[:len(x)/2] + 'b'*(len(x) / 2))
>>> random.shuffle(x)
>>> x = ''.join(x)
>>> x
'bbbaabbaaa'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of volatility's answer that lets you specify a percentage

```
def replace_ramd(input_string, pct):
    for r in range(len(input_string)):
        yield input_string[r] if random.randint(0,100) > pct else chr(random.randint(64,127))
```